# Linq query has a bug?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

Just look at the linq query and the SQL profiler resulting query. Linq repeats the subquery which it shouldn't. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? By the way, I know how to write this linq to give me a satisfying result, but I want to know why is this one badly interpreted?

```
        return (from k in ctx.UzajamnaKasa
                join p in ctx.UzajamnaKasaPozajmice
                    on k.UzajamnaKasaId equals p.UzajamnaKasaId
                where k.ClanId == clanId
                select p.Iznos + p.Donos -
                    (from ot in ctx.UzajamnaKasaPozajmiceOtplate
                     where p.PozajmicaId == ot.PozajmicaId
                     group ot.Iznos by ot.PozajmicaId into g
                     select g.Sum()).FirstOrDefault()
                ).Sum();



select [GroupBy3].[A1] as [C1]
from
(
    select sum([Project2].[A1]) as [A1]
    from
    (
        select ([Project2].[Iznos] + [Project2].[Donos])
               - (case
                      when ([Project2].[C1] is null) then
                          cast(0 as decimal(18))
                      else
                  (
                      select top (1)
                             [GroupBy2].[A1] as [C1]
                      from
                      (
                          select [Extent4].[PozajmicaId] as [K1]
                               , sum([Extent4].[Iznos])  as [A1]
                          from [dbo].[UzajamnaKasaPozajmiceOtplate] as [Extent4]
                          where [Project2].[PozajmicaId] = [Extent4].[PozajmicaId]
                          group by [Extent4].[PozajmicaId]
                      ) as [GroupBy2]
                  )
                  end
                 ) as [A1]
        from
        (
            select [Extent2].[PozajmicaId] as [PozajmicaId]
                 , [Extent2].[Iznos]       as [Iznos]
                 , [Extent2].[Donos]       as [Donos]
                 , (
                       select top (1)
                              [GroupBy1].[A1] as [C1]
                       from
                       (
                           select [Extent3].[PozajmicaId] as [K1]
                                , sum([Extent3].[Iznos])  as [A1]
                           from [dbo].[UzajamnaKasaPozajmiceOtplate] as [Extent3]
                           where [Extent2].[PozajmicaId] = [Extent3].[PozajmicaId]
                           group by [Extent3].[PozajmicaId]
                       ) as [GroupBy1]
                   )                       as [C1]
            from [dbo].[UzajamnaKasa]                    as [Extent1]
                inner join [dbo].[UzajamnaKasaPozajmice] as [Extent2]
                    on [Extent1].[UzajamnaKasaId] = [Extent2].[UzajamnaKasaId]
            where [Extent1].[ClanId] = 1303
        ) as [Project2]
    ) as [Project2]
) as [GroupBy3];
```

Why is he duplicating this select? It's bad for performace.:

```
 select top (1)
                             [GroupBy2].[A1] as [C1]
                      from
                      (
                          select [Extent4].[PozajmicaId] as [K1]
                               , sum([Extent4].[Iznos])  as [A1]
                          from [dbo].[UzajamnaKasaPozajmiceOtplate] as [Extent4]
                          where [Project2].[PozajmicaId] = [Extent4].[PozajmicaId]
                          group by [Extent4].[PozajmicaId]
                      ) as [GroupBy2]
```

Comment: If efficient queries is important than never rely on any framework or library to write the query for you. Write it yourself. Even if you get it working now, after an update of the framework it could be bad again...

Comment: We can assume that the query optimizer will remove unnecessary parts of the code. What does the query execution plan show?

Comment: It shows two times index seek on UzajamnaKasaPozajmiceOtplate.PozajmicaId.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    (from ot in ctx.UzajamnaKasaPozajmiceOtplate
                 where p.PozajmicaId == ot.PozajmicaId
                 group ot.Iznos by ot.PozajmicaId into g
                 select g.Sum()).FirstOrDefault()
```

Due to the FirstOrDefault(), this sub-query will be executed for every p.PozajmicaId founded.

Comment: Well, that is what I want and after that result, I have final Sum.
Problem is why is he duplicating this code
 "select top (1)
                             [GroupBy2].[A1] as [C1]..."